# MATLAB: parfor loop and for loop giving different results on same image sets

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to run a parfor loop to do some image processing but am getting different results when I run it as a parfor versus when I just run it as a for. In the below part of the code, I always seem to get the same result for the first variable (refNUM, IMAGEfeatures{i}(1)) but slightly different for the second (empNUM, IMAGEfeatures{i}(1)). I've tried different variations of image loading etc., can't figure out the issue.

```
imageset=uint8(load(imagefile));
[z,x,num_images]=size(imageset);
imageset2=cell();
for i:num_images
    imageset2{i}=imageset(:,:,i);
end

IMAGEfeatures=cell(1,2);

parfor i=1:num_images
    loadimage=imageset2{i};
    jpgsize=size(loadimage);
    [z,x]=size(loadimage);

    dc_est=imresize(loadimage,[z,floor(x/10)]);
    dc_est=imgaussfilt(dc_est,[1,111]);
    dc_est=imresize(dc_est,[z,x]);
    mask_ref=ones(size(loadimage,1),1)*(mean(loadimage-dc_est,1)>15);
    refNUM=sum(sum(mask_ref))/prod(jpgsize);
    IMAGEfeatures{i}{1}=refNUM;

    loadimageEMP=imageset2{i}-im2uint8(mask_ref);
    empNUM=median(mean(loadimageEMP(loadimageEMP>0)));
    IMAGEfeatures{i}{2}=empNUM;

end
```

Comment: Can you verify some possible typos in your sample code: colon at the end of line 3, the range of the first for loop, closing brackets on the `mask_ref=` and `dc_est=` lines. What is different in the results?

Comment: Yea sorry that was lazy typing on my part. The parfor version has a consistently smaller result for empNUM when pulled from IMAGEfeatures, refNUM is equal in either version.

Comment: sorry the parfor is consistently slightly higher, not lower

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `mask_ref=` line when you do a matrix multiplication of ones (`ones(size(loadimage,1),1)*`)? Also do you mean to to be doing `IMAGEfeatures{i,2}` (though what you have may well work...)?

Comment: Did a little more research, sum(sum(imageset2{i})) is the same in both loops, sum(sum(mask_ref)) is the same in both loops, but the result when I subtract im2uint8(mask_ref) from imageset2{i} is slightly different in the parfor versus the for...no idea why, looks like if i im2uint8(imageset2{i}) then the results match up

Comment: Are the differences more or less than 10^-15?

Comment: considerably more